# why after authentication completes(call authenticateWithCompletionHandler method), Game Kit don't calls the block object provided by my game?

Tags: iphone, game-center, gamekit

When I call authenticateWithCompletionHandler method to authorise AGC, then I click Cancel button and close the UI. If later I call authenticateWithCompletionHandler again, this time Game Kit don't calls the block object provided by my game.

Who can tell me why?

my code are as follows:

```
- (void) authenticateLocalUser {
  NSLog(@"====inside authenticateLocalUser");
  [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
  NSLog(@"==== error is %@", error);
  [self callDelegateOnMainThread: @selector(finishAuthenticateLocalUser:) withArg: NULL error: error];
```

}];
}

log are as followings:

```
2012-06-20 19:24:06.569 HighNoon[4140:707] ====inside authenticateLocalUser
2012-06-20 19:24:06.571 HighNoon[4140:707] authenticateWithCompletionHandler: enter
2012-06-20 19:24:06.572 HighNoon[4140:707] authenticateWithCompletionHandler: exit
```

Comment: Are you logging in successfully?

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu The first time I click "Cancel" button and close the pop alert. few minutes later I call authenticateLocalUser method again, this time Game Kit don't calls the block object provided by my game.

Comment: what is happening is: after you cancel game center a several times (3, if I remember correctly), the game center gets disabled and you have to go to the game center app to login again.

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu but I just cancel once, and even through game center gets disabled, why it don't call block object provided by my game, and why there is no error log?

Comment: This may be a bug in iOS 5.1: http://openradar.appspot.com/11644144

Comment: Calling the method only sets the authentication handler. It executes only when the OS tells it to. Setting the auth handler repeatedly won't trigger it.